# Removing a specific key of ModelState for a specific controller's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller for Post and Put request for the same entity: `MyModelDTO` with some ModelState's attributes.

The users can make a `Post` request without the `Id` attribute, because it is being generated on server side, but for `Put` request the `Id` attribute is needed (And has to be different than an empty guid).

I want to allow get a Post request without the "Id" property, and still use the `ModelState` functionality, the best solution I've came across is overriding the `OnActionExecuting` and removing the specific key:

```
public class ExceptPropertiesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _propertiesKeys;

    public ExceptPropertiesAttribute(string commaSeperatedPropertiesKeys)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commaSeperatedPropertiesKeys))
        {
            this._propertiesKeys = commaSeperatedPropertiesKeys.Split(',');
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        if (this._propertiesKeys != null)
        {
            foreach (var propertyKey in this._propertiesKeys)
            {
                if (actionContext.ModelState.ContainsKey(propertyKey))
                {
                    actionContext.ModelState.Remove(propertyKey);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

`MyModelDTO` class:

```
public class EventModelDTO : IBaseModel
{
    [IsNotEmpty(ErrorMessage = "Guid Id Is Empty")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class IsNotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;

        var valueType = value.GetType();
        var emptyField = valueType.GetField("Empty");

        if (emptyField == null) return true;

        var emptyValue = emptyField.GetValue(null);

        return !value.Equals(emptyValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpPost]
[ExceptPropertiesAttribute("Id")]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody] MyModelDTO itemDTO = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        MyModel item = _mapper.Map<MyModel>(itemDTO);
        ResultService result = this._myService.Insert(item);
        if (result.Success)
        {                    
            return CreatedAtAction("Post", new { item.Id }, itemDTO);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(500, result.ErrorCode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ErrorCode.Unknown);
    }
}

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public ActionResult Put([FromBody] MyModelDTO itemDTO)
{
    try
    {                
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        MyModel item = _mapper.Map<MyModel>(itemDTO);
        ResultService result = this._eventsService.Update(item);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(500, result.ErrorCode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ErrorCode.Unknown);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `ModelState` bound to an `Id` that you need this workaround? Please describe the problem you are solving with more details.

Comment: @t3chb0t see updated question, it checks if the Id is not null or empty guid

Comment: If I understand it correctly your entities have an `Id` property that is decorated with the `IsNotEmptyAttribute` and for certain requests you'd like to exclude this validation of the model?

Comment: Hey guys, see updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your approach might work, I consider it a ***hack***. The preferred solution would be to **create different models for *each* request** so that the user does not have a chance of passing values that might not only not be required but even be forbidden.

Your new entities could be:

```
class NewUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where there are is no `Id` if the AIP does not require it.

---

It is a very bad idea to expose your database models to the caller. Create more specific models and map their properties to your database entities.

If you let the user the possibility of passing anything he wants, you would need to validate even more values to be sure he does not try to do something else than you want him to.

One such example could be when you have an API for updating `User.Name` but that user has a navigation property `Books` and the caller sends you some books too that will also get updated... just because he can. This might cause you a lot of trouble.

Comment: So you are saying to create a `MyModelPostRequest` and a `MyModelPutRequest`, I didn't exposed my db model to users, see the DTO suffix and the Mapper in updated question.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani you might not use db-entities directly but these dtos look a lot like the entities; I bet they are identical... if they weren't then you wouldn't have to create workarounds for ignoring some properties that obviously don't belong there in certain requests.

Comment: I see, agreed, the lesson for me is to create separate request classes for Put and Post, leave the DTO only for Get request...